# Import working in python shell, but not when running a script

Tags: python, python-import, caffe, raspberry-pi3

I have installed caffe to run google deep dream on my raspberry pi, but i have encountered some unexpected behavior.

when i import caffe via the python shell it works fine:

```
>>> import caffe
>>>
```

But when i run the deepdreaming.py (https://github.com/JoBergs/deepdream) i get an ImportError:

```
pi@raspberrypi: sudo python deepdreaming.py -s img.jpg -r
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "deepdreaming.py", line 15, in <module>
import caffe
ImportError: No module named caffe
```

My PYTHONPATH:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/deepdream/deepdream $ $PYTHONPATH
-bash: /home/pi/deepdream/caffe/python: Is a directory
```

When i add:

```
 sys.path.append("/home/pi/deepdream/caffe/python")
```

to deepdreaming.py everything works fine.

Could anyone help me shed some light on why this is happening?
It seems like python is not checking PYTHONPATH when i run it with a script.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried without `sudo` ? I'm running windows here, but doesn't `sudo` inherit root environment and thus not your `PYTHONPATH` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh yeah, that explains a whole lot. I was using sudo because i was accessing some files i did not own. Looks like i've got some chowning to do! Thank you!